# How can I create a block shadow effect for text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I want to recreate this image in illustrator. I'm looking to create two tone 3-d colors with a variety of different fonts.

[image]

Comment: "Step by step" guides aren't really what this site is about. Show us what you've tried, where you are having difficulty, and ask *specific* questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to help you create your own font, but if you only have a few words to do, like say for a logo, you could type the words using a sans-serif font, then trace them with the Pen tool or use Type > Create Outlines to get a 2D path based off the words. Then you could add the "shadow" with the Pen tool as well.

Or, you could take a 2D shape (created by tracing a typed word or by taking a typed word and doing Type > Create Outlines) and use Effect > 3D > Extrude and Bevel to make it look like 3D blocks like your example